# Why Symbol in clojure can be used as Functions?

Tags: clojure, symbols

I refer you to this short code:

```
('a 1)
;==> nil
('a 1 2)
;=>2
```

why can the symbol `a` be used as a function in this context?

Comment: i perfectly understand how symbolic resolution work in clojure.but
what i fail to understand is why a symbol (bound our unbound)
behave like a function

Comment: i checked the two posts and i get that symbols and keywords can be used as function to perform lookup in a map .but why the code above works because it shouldn't

Comment: Why? The simplest answer is because clojure.lang.Symbol implements the IFn interface. What are the rules for using it that way? See the above link from Chiron. Why did they choose to make symbols behave that way? For convenience.

Comment: @user3228423 yes, in your example 1 is the map and 2 is the "not found" default, as long 1 is not a map the not found 2 is returned

Comment: If you want to unerstand that behavior look at `get`. A symbol used as a function effectively calls get, and get will take anything as a first arg, simply returning the default if it cannot get something from it. `(get Double/NaN :a :default)` => :default

Comment: The above was mentioned in A. Webb's link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to look up a map with the symbol as a key, in a nice syntax.

Below are equivalent:

```
('a my-hash-map)
(get my-hash-map 'a)  ; returns value associated with 'a or nil if not present
```

For further convenience, you can also supply default value as optional second argument:

```
('a my-hash-map 42)  ; returns 42 if my-hash-map does't have the key 'a
```

As to you example, *('a 1)* returns *nil* because *(get 1 'a)* returns *nil*, and  *('a 1 2)* returned supplied default value, 2.